# Ruby summing duration of datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Each user has many experiences, an experience has a period start and period end date, and I need to sum that delta across all experiences.

I found this as a solution which comes up with an error for too many arguments.

```
<%=
  current_user.experiences.sum("strftime('%s', period_end) - strftime('%s', period_start)")
%>
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? On PG you would do `SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (period_end - period_start)))`

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide more context: what is the type of `period_start` and `period_end`?

Comment: Also, what output are you expecting? can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to sum the total differences between start and end times right?  If so you should be able to just do:

```
<%= current_user.experiences
     .pluck(:period_start, :period_end)
     .map{|d| (d[0].to_f - d[1].to_f).abs}.sum %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that code is going into an html.erb file, I'd suggest making the following method on your experience model:

```
class Experience << ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def period_duration_in_seconds
    (period_end - period_start).to_i.abs
  end
end
```

In your user model:

```
class User << ApplicaitonRecord
  ...

  def sum_of_experiences_duration
    experiemces.sum(&:period_duration_in_seconds)
  end
end
```

And finally in your html.erb file, you can call:

```
<%= Time.at(current_user.sum_of_experiences_duration).utc.strftime "%S" %>
```

Note that will give you the difference in seconds, if you want different formats check out the strftime options:

https://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Comment: `to_i.` will round seconds, probably better to use `.to_f` when processing time.

Comment: Also this takes the "dump arbitrary methods in the model" approach, when if this is used only in the view, a helper would make more sense.

Comment: I'm curious how you would have structured it?

Comment: See my answer above, but maybe I would moved that to a helper, or instantiate an object from it in the controller. You answer is not "wrong", just a lot more than what is needed for OPs usecase IMHO. If the code is only used in the view, why add code in 2 models unless this will be shared in different views/controllers or re-used for other model data related purposes, i.e reporting.